# Would this characters shadow not reveal his secret?

Tags: dragonlance, war-of-souls

In the *Chronicles* series, we meet Silvara who is a Silver Dragon in human form. When she explains to Gilthanas and company that she's a dragon, she points to her shadow, which is dragon-shaped.

Fast forward to *Dragons of a Lost Star*.

> Glaucous

confronts Mina in her prisoners tent while Silvanoshei watches from outside. Later it is revealed that he is

> Cyan Bloodbane in elven disguise thanks to an amulet given him by Raistlin.

Question is, shouldn't his shadow have given him away still? Or did the amulet hide that fact as well?

Answer (score 4):

A likely or justifiable reason for this discrepancy would be that Silvara is in her elven form due to an innate ability of Silver dragons to take a humanoid form.

From your description, the amulet is what gave Cyan the ability.   The mechanics of the amulet were likely a general polymorph magic rather than innate draconic magic, with its betraying shadow.

It is also possible that incidental shadows do not show the startling draconic silhouette, as surely Silvara had walked down a torch-lit hallway or even just out in the sunlight.   If her (and other dragons') shadow was always in the shape of a dragon, it would be extremely easy to detect.

It may take a deliberate action on the part of the dragon (as Silvara did) to reveal their shadow.

Comment: I reread the part where Silvara shows how shadow several time, and it feels like they just never paid attention to it, not that she had to "will it" into form, you know? But, I could be wrong. You've got a decent answer, and I appreciate it. :)

Comment: Oh, it is very possible that the author's didn't give it any thought beyond writing that scene, and may have not have recalled Silvara's scene (written many years previously) when writing Dragons of a Lost Star.

Comment: That's true. 20 years can do things to the mind, lmao